# Bigger brackets

Tags: brackets

I would like to get the two outer brackets are bigger than the others. How can this be done? I've tried using \big before the first bracket but that didn't work

```
\Corr (\left(a^{-j}\right)}^tX_j, {\left(b^{-j}\right)}^tY_j)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\left` and `\right` can be nested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(\left(a^{-j}\right)^t X_j, \left(b^{-j}\right)^t Y_j\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Also the enlargement of the inner brackets is not really necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left((a^{-j})^t X_j, (b^{-j})^t Y_j\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result 2]

Comment: I better appreciate the second solution; however, `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` for the outer parentheses would be sufficient (and also the input clearer).

Comment: @egreg As far as I can see, the sizes are the same here (second example). `\bigl` and friends do not add the additional horizontal space, which `\left` and `\right` are setting around. Package `mleftright` provides `\mleft` and `\mright` for a `\left` and `\right` without the additional space.